# header location remove some variable online

Tags: php, url

I use header location in php to redirect and take some variable with it. This works fine on localhost, but the problem is online.

```
header("location:addactivities.php?s=$projectname&c=$client&msg=1&action");
```

After submit a message should appear that is complete this message appear on localhost but online no

On localhost the url look like this

```
http://localhost/order/projectmanagment/addactivities.php?s=xxxxx&c=test%20edit&msg=1&action
```

But online, it looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/projectmanagment/addactivities.php?s=test&c=test
```

I can't get the message `msg` and print the result of it.

Comment: At live URL you didn't pass *msg* in query string that's why you are not able to get in result i think.

Comment: Do you set header information otherwise on `addactivies.php`?

Comment: @AlbertAkki what you please ?!

Comment: @rbr94 i do this header("location:addactivities.php?s=$projectname&c=$client&msg=1&action"); and it work on local